# Hide softkeyboard in single activity - Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have been searching the 'net for a bit here, I can't seem to stop the SoftKeyboard from appearing when an EditText gets focus, I've tried at least 3 different methods, setting the Input Type to None (think I saw that in the Android Dev Docs), and two different ways inside the onCreate method, they are:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

And

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

I know I can disable it for the entire app in the manifest file, but I only need it disabled in this activity.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to do more just place below code in your manifest.xml for perticular activity...

> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
>   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, although I only needed android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden".

Answer (score -1):

for this one whenever u want key board at that only u write soft keyboard appear,likebelow code

```
EditText EditTextName=findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(EditTextName), 0);
```

In above code i am enable the keyboard when edittext has focus.In the same way u disable the keyboard using

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInput(EditTextName), 0);
```