# Any way to disable EditText from editing in Android ICS but still make it highlightable?

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, highlight

I'm making an application that will store a page of text. This application should read highlighted text shown on the screen and pronounce it for the user. The problem is that when I disable the EditText from editing, I can't set highlight in the EditText anymore.

I use this code for disabling:

```
contentBox.setKeyListener(null);
```

And this code for setting highlight:

```
contentBox.setSelection(0,findNextLineIndex(0));
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I found another way to achieve this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769307/hide-softkeyboard-in-single-activity-android

Comment: by letting edittext still editable. just hide the softkeyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `android:editable="false"` to disable it; then u can get its focus :) cheers :)

Comment: normally, I want to use edittext as textview but still can set highlight on it. it works on ginger bread. but the highlight doesn't show up on ics.

Comment: can u show me your code or some snippets? i may get some more idea :)